# White bottom bar swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, navigationbar

I tried making the UI of my app a bit better by adding a dark background and making the nav bar dark as well, but there's a white bar at the top that I just cannot get rid of. The currency selector was down there but I moved it up, but i'm stuck with that bar. I presume it's part of the navigation controller, though when I click on it it shows me the attributes of the table view. [The top of the navigation bar changed color.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOdmY.png)

In the `UITableViewController`, in `viewDidLoad` I have the following:

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
        navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        currencySelector.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7)
        currencySelector.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the bar at the bottom simply the toolbar?

Comment: It might be, but when I tried to edit it programatically I got an error saying view controller has no toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
navigationController?.toolbarHidden = true
```

Comment: I'm not sure what it is exactly, since clicking on it doesn't do much help. I did  add a toolbar to the Nav Controller and made it black - I know it's not a solution to the problem, but until I can figure out exactly what that is, it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, make sure you haven't set your UITableViewController's bottom bar to be a Toolbar. It should be set to "Inferred", or even explicitly set to "None".

[image: Interface Builder]

Answer (score 0):

Go into your navigation controller on the SB editor.  You should be able to select the Nav Bar itself and see options like this:[NavBar Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxfDr.png)

Also, the navigation controller itself has a show toolbar option, you probably just have that turned on.

It's also possible that the view that is providing your dark background has constraints set to the bottom of the screen equivalent to a toolbar height.